# could not compile used unit "IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge", delphi 2005

Tags: delphi, delphi-2005

I have this problem for days now. I have a delphi app that i tried to run in my laptop. This program runs very good in other computer, but when i try to copy the program in my laptop, it displays LOTS of errors:

```
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(46): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TIdPeerThread'
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(104): E2170 Cannot override a non-virtual method
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(238): E2029 ')' expected but identifier 'Connection' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(238): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(242): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(242): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(242): E2014 Statement expected, but expression of type 'string' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(243): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(243): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(244): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(244): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(245): E2029 ':=' expected but ':' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(245): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(246): E2153 ';' not allowed before 'ELSE'
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(249): E2029 '.' expected but ';' found
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(308): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(308): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(451): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(451): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(499): E2037 Declaration of 'Create' differs from previous declaration
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(501): E2075 This form of method call only allowed in methods of derived types
[Error] IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas(502): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'FOkToProcessCommand'
[Fatal Error] Primews.dpr(145): F2063 Could not compile used unit 'SourceServerBase\IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas'
```

I dont know how to solve this problem on my own since its my first time tbhat i have encountered this. Any suggestions of what should i do? thank you all guys.

**Got new problem**
I didn't make a change after i posted this problem. Now, it displays new error message saying:

```
[Fatal Error] Primews.dpr(67): F2051 Unit DBClient was compiled with a different version of DSIntf.szFIELDNAME
```

What does it mean?
By the way, I am using delphi 2005 personal in my laptop.
    enter code here

Comment: What version of Delphi is your computer using?

Comment: @Reme, I am using Delphi2005 personal in my laptop.

Comment: now ,it displays new error. I didn't change any. Error is: '[Fatal Error] Primews.dpr(67): F2051 Unit DBClient was compiled with a different version of DSIntf.szFIELDNAME'

Comment: I asked what your **computer** is using, not your **laptop**.  You said other computers are working fine, but your laptop is not working.  So what is different between their setups?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TIdPeerThread` is a class in Indy 9 and earlier. It does not exist in Indy 10.  It was replaced with `TIdContext`. So you are using the wrong version of `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` for your laptop's version of Indy. You can get the latest version of Indy 10 and `IdHTTPWebBrokerBridge.pas` from Indy's SVN server or Fulgan mirror. Links to both are on [Indy's website](http://www.indyproject.org).

Comment: now ,it displays new error. I didn't change any. Error is: '[Fatal Error] Primews.dpr(67): F2051 Unit DBClient was compiled with a different version of DSIntf.szFIELDNAME'

Comment: @jayAnn please ask a new question for that, and link it to this question.